# GitBook: Is it possible to create links in code blocks?

Tags: gitbook

I realize that normally when you describe some code (in a GitBook or anywhere else):

```
var foo = bar();
```

you don't want to add links to it.  However, for some documentation I'm writing it would be really great if I could somehow add a link inside the code:

```
var foo = bar(); // "bar" links to a page describing bar
```

Is there any way to achieve this, possibly using a GitBook plug-in, HTML instead of Markdown, or some other inconvenient technique?

Answer (score 0):

I found a "poor man's" solution to the problem, but if there are any better ones I'd love to hear them.

Essentially Markdown just converts indented code in to:

```
<pre><code>*the code*</code></pre>
```

Inside a `<code>` tag `<a>` tags (links) won't work, but they do work inside a `<pre>`, and a `<pre>` by itself *almost* looks like code block.  Of course you don't get the syntax coloring with this approach, but at least it does offer a way to add links to code examples.